# Algorithm for checking linear independence of algebraic numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

Is there any if and only if condition for checking $\mathbb{Q}$-linear independence of given a set of numbers say $\alpha_i$ ? More precisely how to check linear independence of given $n$ algebraic numbers (algebraic numbers are given by an interval and its irreducible polynomial such that that interval does not contain any other root of that polynomial ) ? Is there any known algorithm for it?

PS : Def : $\alpha_i$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly dependent iff $ \exists c_i \in \mathbb{Q} $ not all zero such that $\sum c_i\alpha_i=0$

Comment: There certainly exist such algorithms. Just construct the field generated by all these $\alpha_i$, and the problem reduces to checking whether a determinant is non-zero. Unfortunately I cannot give a reference, but there are many good books about computational number theory that you can have a look.

Comment: With some search I found GTM 138: A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory, which might be a good reference for you. But note that this book may not contain some of the new algorithms.

Comment: Which determinant? Can you elaborate? are you aware that they are efficient or not? I will look at the book . I think there is some algorithm using LLL . But I am not sure.

Comment: They are efficient enough at least for a small number of inputs. The key point you need is probably the factorization of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, for which some efficient algorithm involving LLL exist.

Comment: Okay, thanks. There is an another related question which I could not find (most probably related to this one). Suppose you are given $n$ algebraic numbers $a_i$ , how to check whether $\sum \alpha_i = 0$ ? See using linear independence you can give a NP algorithm (find the maximal independent set and then guess the coefficients of others while writing in terms of the maximal elements and then check whether all coefficients are indeed 0 or not) . But I guess there is a similar Polytime algorithm for this also but could not find anything. Can we give a polytime algo for this also?

Comment: It's the determinant of the matrix induced by the trace-form. If you already got the reference (Cohen), it is in Proposition 4.4.1 of 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, so I figure I might as well spell it out explicitly for the next person who comes across this post.

For convenience, [here](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/A%20course%20in%20computational%20algebraic%20number%20theory%20-%20Cohen.pdf) is a link to the book WhatsUp mentioned in the comments above. One starts by solving the primitive element problem, discussed on page 181, for one's set of numbers. When testing whether $\alpha_1\in\mathbb{Q}(k_1\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$ using one of the field membership algorithms, on success one gets a polynomial $P_1(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\alpha_1=P_1(k_1\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$. Let $\beta_2=k_1\alpha_1+\alpha_2$. Then for $Q_1(x)=x-k_1P_1(x)$, $\alpha_2=Q_1(\beta_2)$. One then similarly finds $P_i(x)$ and $k_i$ such that $\beta_i=P_i(\beta_{i+1})$ where $\beta_{i+1}=k_i\beta_i+\alpha_{i+1}$ and $Q_i(x)$ such that $\alpha_{i+1}=Q_i(\beta_{i+1})$ for each $i$. For $k<i$ one has $\beta_k=P_k(P_{k+1}(...P_{i-1}(P_i(\beta_i))...))$, and substituting this into $Q_{k-1}(x)$, one can get a polynomial for every $a_k$ in terms of the final $b_i$. The matrix whose rows are the coefficients of these polynomials is the relevant one. I don't think it's guaranteed to be square in general, but row reducing and examining the pivots should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to Alex's answer, feel free to turn it into a comment: you can compute the primitive element as follows. By Theorem 4.6 of "Computing primitive elements of extension fields" by Yokoyama et al., $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ has a primitive element of the form $\theta = \alpha_1 + t_2\alpha_2 + \ldots + t_n\alpha_n$, where $1 \le t_i \le [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_i) : \mathbb{Q}]$. Enumerating all such $\theta$'s, it remains to check whether $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. This can be done by factoring the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ into irreducibles in $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, and checking whether the factorisation contains a linear factor. Factorisation in a number field can be done in polynomial time, see "Factoring polynomials over algebraic number fields" by A.K.Lenstra.

There is also the paper by "Polynomial Time Algorithms for Finding Integer Relations Among Real Numbers" by Hastad et al that might be useful.